# Is it possible to deploy Internet Explorer 11 (IE11) via WSUS 3.0 SP2?

Tags: group-policy, deployment, internet-explorer-11, wsus

Internet Explorer 11 is not listed in WSUS, nor can I find the installer on http://catalog.update.microsoft.com/v7/site/Search.aspx?q=Internet+Explorer+11.  There's plenty of updates, but not the actual browser!

What I'm looking for is either the package for WSUS or an MSI that I can deploy via Group Policy.

Comment: I assume your using Windows 7?

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, I'm using Windows 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE11 was finally added to WSUS this week, on Tuesday.  You should now be able to see it and install it. It is an update rollup under kb 2841134

Comment: Spot on.  Thanks Alan.  Looks like I asked the question on the same day it was released :).